# JAVASCRIPT WARNING: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, get, xmlhttprequest, manifest.json

I'm trying building a simple dictionary chrome extension. I found this API online [Text](https://dictionaryapi.dev/) from where I fetched (through an HTTP Request) a string consisting of word details and parsed the string into a JSON object. But when I use the extension, I get this warning regarding Synchronous XMLHttpRequest. I have provided the code below:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Dictionary Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Finds the meaning of the word entered by user",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Hello there! What is it that you're looking for",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "dic.png",
          "32": "dic.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["popup.js"]
      }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

```js
<!--popup.js-->

var url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US"
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var mat = document.getElementById("material");

function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}



button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mat.innerHTML = "";
  var val = input.value;
  var temp_url = url + "/" + val;
  var json_data = httpGet(temp_url);
  var data = JSON.parse(json_data);
  var l = data[0].meanings.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    var len = ((data[0].meanings[i]).definitions).length;
    part_of_speech = (data[0].meanings[i]).partOfSpeech;
    var h1 = document.createElement("h2");
    var list = document.createElement("ol");
    h1.innerHTML = part_of_speech;
    mat.appendChild(h1);

    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      var def = (data[0].meanings[i]).definitions[j].definition;
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = def;
      list.appendChild(li);
    }
    mat.appendChild(list);
  }
});
```

```html
<!--popup.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Find Meaning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello there! What is it that you're looking for?</h1>
  <label for="word">Enter the word</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Word">
  <button id="btn">Find Meaning</button>

  <div id="material"></div>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's what I've tried. I tried changing the 'async' parameter of the function XMLHttpRequestObject.open() to true but then, it gave the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. I searched about this, and came to conclusion that, the function httpGet() is returning the string much later and during that time, the function on the click event of the button is executed. So, now "data" variable is  "undefined" because the value from httpGet has not been returned yet. Thus, it can't parse undefined into a json object.
I'm new to Js and don't know much about HTTP. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into async/await and promises, but the basic changes you need to make are:

```
button.addEventListener("click", async function() {
    // ...
    var json_data = await httpGet(temp_url);
    // ...
})

function httpGet(theUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            resolve(xmlHttp.response);
        } else {
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xmlHttp.statusText
            });
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Now it is working fine. But for the words that don't exist it gives an error; Uncaught (in promise) #<Object>. I searched about it and i found that its about catching the error (Error handling). Can you please guide me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i may refactor/modernize this code a bit i would have done it like this (using the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api instead of the old XMLHttpRequest)

```js
const url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/"
const [form, material] = document.querySelectorAll("form, #material");

// Using form.onsubmit is better then btn.onclick
// Will allow the form to be validated before this function is triggerd
form.addEventListener("submit", async function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  // using promise based fetch API that can be awaited
  const res = await fetch(url + form.elements.word.value)
  // Choose to return json instead of parsing a string
  const data = await res.json()
  material.innerHTML = ''

  // for..of loop makes it easier
  for (const meaning of data[0].meanings) { 
    const h1 = document.createElement('h2')
    const list = document.createElement('ol')
    // using innerText is safer
    h1.innerText = meaning.partOfSpeech
    material.append(h1)

    for (const def of meaning.definitions) {
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.innerText = def.definition
      list.append(li)
    }
    material.append(list)
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello there! What is it that you're looking for?</h1>
<form target="https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/">
  <!-- updated the id to match the input element -->
  <label for="wordInput">Enter the word</label>
  <!-- added the required attribute to the input -->
  <input autofocus id="wordInput" name="word" type="text" required placeholder="Word">
  <button type="submit">Find Meaning</button>
</form>
<div id="material"></div>
```